# Combinar tablas padre-hijo en postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql, herencia

espero me puedan ayudar con esto. Tengo 3 tablas: vehículo(padre), carro(hijo), moto(hijo) con los siguientes campos.

```
Vehículo(id,marca,anio,precio)
Carro(nro_puertas integer) (Heredada de vehículo)
Moto(incluye_access boolean) (Heredada de vehículo)
```

El problema que tengo es que no puedo generar un reporte que muestre lo siguiente:

```
id, marca, anio, precio, nro_puertas, incluye_acces
```

donde habrá algunos `null` en `nro_puertas` y en `incluye_acces`

Esta es la estructura de las tablas:

[image]

Este es el resultado que deseo obtener:

[image]

Comment: Puedes agregar el SQL que llevas realizado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @Cristopher algún error que te esta dando?

Comment: Lo he intentado con esta consulta: `select * from carro car full outer join moto mot on car.id = mot.id` pero esto añade las columnas de moto a las de carro, y lo que necesitaría es que estas se unan, es decir, que no existan dos campos id, dos campos marca, etc